# how to send apikey when using IBM Cloud API?

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I'm trying to call IBM cloud speech to text API directly from my angular project.

```
getAudioFile (text: string) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, {
        text: text
      }, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
          'Accept' : 'audio/wav',
          'authorization' : 'apikey:' + this.apiKey
        },
        params: {
          voice: 'en-US_AllisonV3Voice'
        }
      }).pipe(map(res => console.log(res)), catchError(this.handleError))
  }
```

I got the apiKey and apiUrl from the website specifically for my account (which works as a token). I'm just not sure if I'm sending it the right way. Please help me if you have done this before.

Comment: Are you using an URL like shown here? https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech#authentication-cloud See the warning to NOT use API keys in production when directly using the API. Use shortlived auth tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting the 401 error in 'development' @data_henrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [API documentation and its authentication section](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech#authentication-cloud). If you want to use the API key, then it is used with [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). The username would be "apikey", the password the actual API key. The username and password are base64 encoded. Conceptually, your code would need to look like this:

```
'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + Base64Encoded("apikey"+this.apiKey)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solves 401 error. Though now I get 404 not found!!! Any idea what that is for?

Comment: 404 is "not found". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes Seems like a problem with the URL or resource ID.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the URL and it worked. You saved my life.